# Cannot import opencv besides in site-packages directory with python3

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am following a lynda openCV python course and its opencv installation guide but got stuck on importing the cv2.

I used `pip3 install opencv-python` to install cv2.
I can **only** import cv2 when my current directory is  `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` . Anywhere else would give me

```
  Traceback (most recent call last): 
       File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Following are my system versions:

```
Python 3.6.0
macOS High Sierra 10.13.2
Opencv version '3.4.0'
```

Here's the `__init__.py` found in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2`, not sure how this matters though

```
import importlib
import os

from .cv2 import *
from .data import *

# wildcard import above does not import "private" variables like __version__
# this makes them available
globals().update(importlib.import_module('cv2.cv2').__dict__)
```

### UPDATE

I added this code and it seems to be working from any directory, still question is why do I have to do this? I can just import numpy from anywhere.. weird

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
```

Answer (score 4):

It is because of your cv2.so compiled library file. If you look into your /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/python-3.6 folder (or for some users, its inside /usr/local/python/cv2/python-3.6), you should see the file cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so like so:

```
(cv) fangran@Fangs-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/python-3.6
cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

Now, what you'd want to do is to cd into that directory and rename it to cv2.so (so its easier)

```
(cv) fangran@Fangs-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/python-3.6

(cv) fangran@Fangs-MacBook-Pro python-3.6 % sudo mv cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so cv2.so
```

In case you're in a virtual environment (which is recommended), make sure to do into the site-packages of that environment and do a symlink:

```
(cv) fangran@Fangs-MacBook-Pro site-packages % cd ~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
(cv) fangran@Fangs-MacBook-Pro site-packages % ln -s /usr/local/python/cv2/python-3.6/cv2.so cv2.so
```

or if not, just make sure that whatever env you're in can get access to the cv2.so file.